# How to use Socket.SendAsync to send large data

Tags: c#, sockets, sendasync, socketasynceventargs

```
private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the remote host closed the connection.
    if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            Token token = e.UserToken as Token;
            token.SetData(e);

            Socket s = token.Connection;
            if (s.Available == 0)
            {
                Boolean willRaiseEvent = false;
                // GET DATA TO SEND
                byte[] sendBuffer = token.GetRetBuffer();
                // this.bufferSize IS SocketAsyncEventArgs buffer SIZE
                byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[this.bufferSize];
                int offset = 0;
                int size = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)sendBuffer.Length / (double)this.bufferSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
                {
                    Array.Clear(tempBuffer, 0, this.bufferSize);
                    Array.Copy(sendBuffer, offset, tempBuffer, 0, this.bufferSize);
                    e.SetBuffer(tempBuffer, 0, this.bufferSize);
                    willRaiseEvent = s.SendAsync(e);
                    offset += this.bufferSize;
                }
                int remainSize = sendBuffer.Length - this.bufferSize * (size - 1);
                Array.Clear(tempBuffer, 0, this.bufferSize);
                Array.Copy(sendBuffer, offset, tempBuffer, 0, remainSize);
                e.SetBuffer(tempBuffer, 0, remainSize);
                willRaiseEvent = s.SendAsync(e);

                if (!willRaiseEvent)
                {
                    this.ProcessSend(e);
                }
            }
            else if (!s.ReceiveAsync(e))
            {
                // Read the next block of data sent by client.
                this.ProcessReceive(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ProcessError(e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.CloseClientSocket(e);
    }
}
```

This code is modified from MSDN

Why in circulation, execute `s.SendAsync(e)` the second time, it will be error

> Exception:An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance

How can I send large data ?

Comment: Could you provide the msdn links? I cant find any sendasync example on MSDN. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You have to wait for the `Completed` event to be raised before you can make another asynchronous send. Don't forget to add your own event handler in order for you to get the callback:

```
e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(SendCallback);
```

You can use [my example of an Asynchronous HTTP client](http://codesprout.blogspot.com/2011/04/asynchronous-http-client.html) to model yours:

```
private void BeginSend()
{
    _clientState = EClientState.Sending;
    byte[] buffer = GetSomeData(); // gives you data for the buffer

    SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    e.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(SendCallback);

    bool completedAsync = false;

    try
    {
        completedAsync = _socket.SendAsync(e);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception: " + se.ErrorCode + " Message: " + se.Message);
    }

    if (!completedAsync)
    {
        // The call completed synchronously so invoke the callback ourselves
        SendCallback(this, e);
    }

}
```

Here is the callback method:

```
private void SendCallback(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        // You may need to specify some type of state and 
        // pass it into the BeginSend method so you don't start
        // sending from scratch
        BeginSend();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket Error: {0} when sending to {1}",
               e.SocketError,
               _asyncTask.Host);
    }
}
```

After the callback is complete, you can make another call to `BeginSend` again, until you're done sending data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you have to wait until `Completed` is raised. I think, it is also not the purpose of async programing to wait for any event.

But the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` can only be reused if the last action is completed. So, you can resolve the issue just by create a new `SocketAsyncEventArgs` within each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: you may use blocked socket, this return after completition or error, but it must be in another thread.